# Intercepting View Rendering to add Html helper to ViewData dictionary

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need the Html helper from a view to be accessed inside a template, so I can do this inside a view:

```
ViewData["RootHtmlHelper"]=Html;
```

Inside the template this html helper can so be catched.

But how to do that without changing anything in the original view code which doesn't have the line `"ViewData["RootHtmlHelper"]=Html;"` ? 
Does have a way to do that using `IViewEngine` ? 
During View life-cycle where the Html helper starts to be "alive" ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot of things, like partial views, RazorEngine, ... and a wrapping to `EditorForModel()`.

In my own `EditorForModel()` I wrapped a call to the original `EditorForModel()` and before to call it, I setted in `ViewData` a referece to `Html helper`. In my template I can recover the `Html helper` from `ViewData`, and all worked well, without to use stubs in all my views.

Comment: Don't forget that you can accept your own answer in a little while. = )